# Chartjs unexpected resize and crop after updating data. Using laravel blade view and Livewire

Tags: laravel, chart.js, laravel-livewire

My chart is initially loaded through the code shown below. This works fine.

Then through a Livewire event I update the data. I can see in the data property in the source that the data is correctly updated in the myChart object, so this seems to be working as well.

The problem is that after the update, the chart renders incorrectly. It's cropped, seems zoomed in and it's about 20% or so of the original size at first load. Because of this I can't see if the data refresh and update happens correctly, but as indicated I can see in the source code that the data is updated in the object correctly.

**Update**

Livewire re-renders the whole thing below, so updating the data is actually not needed as that already happens. Not sure why the chart isn't rendered correctly when updating the page. Using the `.clear()` or `.render()` methods doesn't work.

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
labels: [
    @foreach($chart_data as $d)
        '{{ $d['date'] }}',
    @endforeach
],
datasets: [{ 
    data: [
        @foreach($chart_data as $d)
            {{ $d['score'] }},
        @endforeach
    ],

// ... rest of all the Chart config left out for readability

document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
window.livewire.hook('afterDomUpdate', () => {

    var updatedLabels = [
        @foreach($chart_data as $d)
            '{{ $d['date'] }}',
        @endforeach
    ];

    var updatedData = [
        @foreach($chart_data as $d)
            {{ $d['score'] }},
        @endforeach
    ];

    myChart.data.labels.push(updatedLabels);
    myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(updatedData);
    });

    myChart.update({
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should add wire:ignore to your canvas tag, if part of a component it will rerender to initial state by Livewire.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/third-party-libraries/
Look for section  => Ignoring DOM-changes (using wire:ignore)